# Cannot find save handler wincache - in Azure PHP

Tags: php, azure, session, cakephp, wincache

I hosted a web app on Azure using `CakePHP 2.X` on windows platform. I use the wincache session handler `(session.save_handler = wincache)`. Today I have had a problem. My PHP scripts which create sessions to login to my dashboard didn't work(keeps logging me out) while I didn't change anything to this code.

> Warning Error: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'wincache' -
>   session startup failed in.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual tells you to check `phpinfo()` to verify that `wincache` is installed.

http://php.net/manual/en/wincache.installation.php

> Save the phpinfo.php file in the root folder of a IIS web site that uses PHP, then open a browser and make a request to http://localhost/phpinfo.php. Search within the returned web page for a section called wincache. If the extension is enabled, then the phpinfo output will list the configuration settings provided by the WinCache.

The error message means what it's saying. It's not there.

> My PHP scripts which create sessions to login to my dashboard didn't work(keeps logging me out) while I didn't change anything to this code.

This is not a coding problem.

You need to check your wincache installation and maybe re-install it.

Comment: In phpinfo, under wincache section - opcache = disabled, file cache = disabled